# vscode doesn't recognize py-solc-x doesnt library

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to compile a .sol with py-solc-x.
I downloaded the library with pip install py-solc-x but still, vscode doesn't recognize it.
please help me fix this.

[The massage after pip install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Ln9.png)

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6BnU.png)

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: Maybe you have two Pythons installed and you installed module in one Python but you run code in other Python. You could run `print( sys.executable )` to get `/full/path/to/python` and use it to install module `/full/path/to/python -m pip install ...`

Comment: it is not important if vscode recognizes it - it is important if you can run it without error messages.

Comment: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bjze.png) hi its me from a different account this is the screenshot, all the python versions are the same and still it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

You create virtual environment and then install it. I get alot of imports error in pycahrm and vscode for packages.

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip3 install py-solc-x
```

Also the way you import package is not correct. this is how you should setp:

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
# whichever version u want to use
install_solc("0.8.0")
```

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'solcx' still

Answer (score 2):

You have installed the `solcx` in the global python310 environment, please check which python interpreter you have selected from the bottom-left on the VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the same tutorial and ran into the same issue as you.  I followed @Steven-MSFT's tip and got the code to work. Take a look:

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc

_solc_version = "0.6.0"
install_solc(_solc_version)

with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()

    # Compile our solidity
    compiled_sol = compile_standard(
        {
            "language": "Solidity",
            "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
            "settings": {
                "outputSelection": {
                    "*": {"*": ["metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
                }
            },
        },
        solc_version=_solc_version,
    )

    print(compiled_sol)
```

Then I ran `python3 deploy.py`  and it successfully outputted the ABI JSON object!

Answer (score 0):

I also founded this issue. The problem is Python is install globally but site package is in user appdata, in your case "C:\users\kin...\python310\site-packages".
i had uninstalled python and deleted python310 folder in user appdata then installed python and packages again, this time in vscode python extnsion setting page tick "Global module installation".
i hope this work for you too.